# How to redirect a packets from port 80 VM1 to port 8080 VM2?

Tags: debian, iptables, tcp

I want to redirect all packets incoming to 192.168.1.2 port 80 to 192.168.1.1 port 8080, but what I am doing wrong here? On VM2
`iptables -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.2 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT -d 192.168.1.1 --to-port 8080`

Comment: i am not a expert but one must be source -s and the destination is -d afaik?

Comment: Why do you believe this is not working? My guess is that it is, but there is the return path is not behaving as you expect? You might want to describe your wider network  better - I suspect this could be a nat issue or reverse path filtering issue, but unless we know about the source of the packets and network topology we can't answer.

Comment: TCP, both machines don't have NAT adapter, but they have a route to a network with NAT.

Comment: When I use netcat on VM1  192.168.1.1 port 8080, VM2 192.168.1.2 and telnet on any other machine in my network messages don't appear on VM1 port 8080.